# What is the value of $x$ if $x^x = x$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

What is the value of $x$ if $$x^x = x?$$
Can somebody show step by step please. Thanks!

Comment: What about $1$?

Comment: x is either 1 or -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:$\;\;$$x^{x} = x\;,\;$

Taking the logarithms on both the sides of equation we get

$             x\times\log (|x|) = \log (|x|)$

$ \therefore \;\:  (x - 1)\times\log (|x|) = 0$

For the above equation to be true

Either $\;\;$$x-1 = 0\;\;$ or $ \;\;$$\log (|x|) =0$

Therefore $\;\;$$x = 1\;\;$ or $\;\;$$|x| = 1$.

Hence, the solution is $\;\;$$x = 1\;\;$ or $\;\;$$x = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $x\ne0$

So, we have $$x^{x-1}=1$$

For $a^b=1$

either $a=1$

or $a=-1,b$ even

or $b=0$

Comment: @Alex, Exactly. That was my first statement, right?

Comment: How does one know those are the only solutions to $a^b =1$?

Comment: @fleablood, If $$a>1, b>0, a^b>1$$ and for $$a>1, b<0, a^b<1$$ and so on

Comment: And how do you know *that*?